# CreateFile vs fopen vs ofsteam advantage & disadvantage?

Tags: c++, c

`CreateFile` vs `fopen` vs `ofsteam` - *advantage & disadvantage*?

I heard that CreateFile powerful but only for windows.
Can you tell what should I use ( on windows) and why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you're doing.  For sequentially reading and writing text files, iostream is definitely the way to go.  For anything involving transactional security or non-standard devices, you'll have to access the system directly (`CreateFile` or `open`).  Even then, for sequential reading and writing of text, the best solution is to define your own `streambuf`, and use that with iostream.

I can't think of any context where `fopen` would be preferable.

Comment: I want power :) write and read binary. only for windows systems.As I heard open and fopen not match to createfile?this true?

Comment: @Eveler: if you want full power, then the fastest thing you can do to process a file is to open it with `CreateFile` and map it into memory with `CreateFileMapping`, as illustrated in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/13/417183.aspx), which is part of an optimization series which starts from [standard C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/10/415991.aspx) and then progressively moves to [Win32 optimized code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/19/420038.aspx). But in most cases simple standard C and C++ are OK.

Comment: `fopen` is a higher level function, replaced by `fstream::open` in C++.  `CreateFile` and `open` are system level functions, the first in Windows, the second in Unix.  They do not offer exactly the same thing, since the systems support different features differently.

Comment: I'll use mem mapping coz I need fast read.Does fopen or open will work with mem mapping?

Comment: @Eveler I've never seen an implementation of `fopen` which uses mem mapping, but it shouldn't be too hard to use it with iostream.  And since you don't seem to have been reading the answers: `open` is a system level function in Unix (I've never heard of it in Windows, where `CreateFile` has the same role); both `fopen` and `fstream` will be built on top of it.

Comment: Why is "iostream" the way to go? No technical evidence of any advantage presented. 
Trying to guess your reasoning, the notable difference is that it's more the OOP C++ way. Which has it's own pros and cons.
"fopen" would be preferable for portability for example. The OP does say "windows" through. If there is no technical advantage for either (like less overhead, relatively faster, etc.)  then it actually doesn't matter which.

Comment: @Sirmabus There are two very strong reasons to use `iostream` over `FILE*`; extendability (you can add operators for your own types, and you can provide custom `streambuf`) and safety (although g++, and maybe other compilers, understands the `printf` format string, and can generate warnings if there is a mismatch in the arguments).

Answer (score 4):

Unless you need the features provided by the Windows file functions (e.g. overlapped I/O) then my suggestion is going with either iostreams in C++ or `FILE` (`fopen` and friends) in C.

Besides being more portable, you can also use formated input/output for text files, and for C++ it's easy to overload the output/input operators for your classes.

Comment: It's also easy to derive from `std::streambuf` and for some of the "special" features (transactional integrity, special devices, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Windows file *memory mapping* you should use `CreateFile` (e.g. the `HANDLE` passed to [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API is the return value of `CreateFile`). Moreover, `CreateFile` offers higher customization options than C and C++ standard file API.

However, if you want to write *portable code*, or if you don't need Windows-specific features, C and C++ standard file APIs are just fine.
In some tests, when processing large data, I noted some performance overhead of C++ I/O streams vs. raw C file API; if you happen to be in cases like this, you could simply wrap raw C file API in some C++ RAII class, and still use it in C++ code.

Comment: I need for large data files from 4GB to 10GB+ and mem mapping I ll use too.

Comment: So if you need memory mapping you can use direct Win32 API calls and wrap them in C++ RAII classes.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you absoulutely need the extra functionality provided by OS API functions (like [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) I'd reccommend using the standard library functions (like `fopen` or `ofstream`). This way your program will be more portable.

The only real advantage of using `CreateFile` that I can think of is overlapped I/O and maybe finer grained access rights.

Comment: Createfile can open file path more than 260 char length.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you will be better of using fopen in C or ofstream in C++. CreateFile gives some extra control over sharing and caching but does not provide formatting functionality.

Comment: So you write a `streambuf` which uses `CreateFile` the way you need to use it, and get the advantages of both.

Comment: I was always wondering, why it is so cumbersome to plug in a new source or destination into the IOstreams. If anything, C++ makes it easy to declare a pure abstract class for a data writer/reader...

Answer (score 1):

I copied my answer from

[fopen or CreateFile in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225742/fopen-or-createfile-in-windows)

which was closed for some reason which escapes me...

1. There is no defined way for fopen() to return the system error code. There might be an undefined way to access errno, but this might or might not be identical with the system error code.
2. Also, I don't think that there is an defined way to access the real system handle (of type HANDLE) which in turn you might want to use to pass on to one of the many win64 system calls which expect such a system handle (e.g. memory mapped IO)
3. Using open() an integer represents the file handle, which is not the system handle (on windows).
4. fopen() does not throw an exception in case of error. In order to have some RAII you would need to wrap it into a class.
5. Wrapping CreateFile() into a class, is not more expensive than wrapping fopen() or open() into a class.
6. Using the C++ feature (std::ofstream, std::ifstream) to write/read to/from files suffers from the same problem as fopen():

   - It does not throw by default on error. In order to enable this feature you need to call some method instead of being able to use some constructor argument -- means for RAII you would need to derive this class (in order to use it as a member/base class which throws on error).
   - It is undefined if one is able to retrieve the system error code from the exception thrown or if the message returned from what() tells you anything about the system error.
   - Using this stream interface there is no real pluggable interface to define the source or destination of reading from or writing to. Overloading the stream interface is quite cumbersome and error prone.
7. Using C like programming (paying attention to or ignoring return codes and manually writing cleanup code) is the source of much evil (remember heart-bleed?)...

Conclusions:

1. write a resource wrapper for CreateFile()/CloseHandle(). Resource wrapper is a class, which performs the do-action in the constructor and the undo-action in the destructor and throws an exception in case of error. There are many such pairs of system calls in every OS but especially in Win64.
2. Write a system error exception class (to be used for the above class in case of CreateFile() fails and for all the other system errors) or investigate, what the new system_exception class (in C++0x) is actually doing and if it is sufficient.
3. write a functional wrapper for ReadFile() and WriteFile() which converts a system error into a system exception object thrown...
4. Potentially define your own interface to write to somewhere and read from somewhere so that you can implement other things independent from the type of source/destination to read from/write to.
5. Writing a cache class which allows you to cache reading from somewhere or writing to somewhere is also child play. Of course the cache class should not know nor care about the source/destination you're writing to/reading from.

Don't be scared about these small tasks. You will actually know, what is happening in your code and these little pieces of code should be negligible (in amount of lines of code) compared to the code calling it. Also if you're using RAII for everything, the code calling into these utility classes, will be considerable less compared to when not using RAII and having to use two- or even more-step initialization and considerable less error prone. Replacing these utility classes with equivalent utility classes for other OS is also child play (using open()/close()/read()/write() on UNIXs).

And for the sake of the previous millennia don't read the google programming guidelines!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious and clear winner is "CreateFile". Why?, because it has the most options. With it you have control over the buffering, can give it some hints for sequential or random access (needs profiling to see if there is any actual performance advantage), plus control over security and sharing.

It fits best within the context of the OP's question of "power".

If you need the extra control and options use "CreateFile", but probably most of the time you are fine with the ubiquitous tried and true "fopen". Or if you are big on C++ OOP mechanics, use "ofsteam".

Comment: *It fits best within the context of the OP's question of "power".*  The OP never defined what that meant, though.

Comment: There are several issues with `CreateFile`; portability is the obvious one. A more important one (since you don't always need portability, and can wrap the call in a portable wrapper -- `open` has pretty much the same possibilities in Posix) is that the handle returned by `CreateFile` doesn't support formatted output. If you need the additional options of `CreateFile`, but are outputting something more than already formatted buffers, you can create a custom `streambuf` which uses `CreateFile`.