# fopen or CreateFile in Windows

Tags: c++

Can any one please let me know whether I need to use fopen() and related functions to open the file, write and read operations or CreateFile() and related functions when working on Windows. Which set of functions are better and what are the advantages.

Comment: What is `CreateFile()`? Not a standard C++ function. (Found it, it's some Microsoft thingy.) -> As long as you never ever need to compile your code on a system other than Windows with MSVC, you can probably use both. In general, I would prefer `fopen` and over that the [`<fstream>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/fstream) facilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no defined way for fopen() to return the system error code. There might be an undefined way to access errno, but this might or might not be identical with the system error code.
2. Also, I don't think that there is an defined way to access the real system handle (of type HANDLE) which in turn you might want to use to pass on to one of the many win64 system calls which expect such a system handle (e.g. memory mapped IO)
3. Using open() an integer represents the file handle, which is not the system handle (on windows).
4. fopen() does not throw an exception in case of error. In order to have some RAII you would need to wrap it into a class.
5. Wrapping CreateFile() into a class, is not more expensive than wrapping fopen() or open() into a class.
6. Using the C++ feature (std::ofstream, std::ifstream) to write/read to/from files suffers from the same problem as fopen():

   - It does not throw by default on error. In order to enable this feature you need to call some method instead of being able to use some constructor argument -- means for RAII you would need to derive this class (in order to use it as a member/base class which throws on error).
   - It is undefined if one is able to retrieve the system error code from the exception thrown or if the message returned from what() tells you anything about the system error.
   - Using this stream interface there is no real pluggable interface to define the source or destination of reading from or writing to. Overloading the stream interface is quite cumbersome and error prone.
7. Using C like programming (paying attention to or ignoring return codes and manually writing cleanup code) is the source of much evil (remember heart-bleed?)...

Conclusions:

1. write a resource wrapper for CreateFile()/CloseHandle(). Resource wrapper is a class, which performs the do-action in the constructor and the undo-action in the destructor and throws an exception in case of error. There are many such pairs of system calls in every OS but especially in Win64.
2. Write a system error exception class (to be used for the above class in case of CreateFile() fails and for all the other system errors) or investigate, what the new system_exception class (in C++0x) is actually doing and if it is sufficient.
3. write a functional wrapper for ReadFile() and WriteFile() which converts a system error into a system exception object thrown...
4. Potentially define your own interface to write to somewhere and read from somewhere so that you can implement other things independent from the type of source/destination to read from/write to.
5. Writing a cache class which allows you to cache reading from somewhere or writing to somewhere is also child play. Of course the cache class should not know nor care about the source/destination you're writing to/reading from.

Don't be scared about these small tasks. You will actually know, what is happening in your code and these little pieces of code should be negligible (in amount of lines of code) compared to the code calling it. Also if you're using RAII for everything, the code calling into these utility classes, will be considerable less compared to when not using RAII and having to use two- or even more-step initialization and considerable less error prone. Replacing these utility classes with equivalent utility classes for other OS is also child play (using open()/close()/read()/write() on UNIXs).

And for the sake of the previous millennia don't read the google programming guidelines!

Comment: See
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35190832/how-can-i-get-the-standard-file-streams-to-return-a-useful-error-message
regarding standard file streams not being able to report useful error messages.

Answer (score 3):

[fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) is a standard function - this means your code should compile also on other standard conformant platforms - linux, apple, ...

actually `fopen` under windows will internally call `CreateFile` so if you dont need any windows specific (non-standard) features, then use `fopen`.

And since you tagged this question as c++ then, I would suggest using more c++ aproach with [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/).

Comment: fopen is a C function. It does not know about RAII. It does not throw on error. So since 1996 it should not be considered anymore as useful.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows `CreateFile()`, in particular `CreateFileW()`, is better as it at least allows to open files with names containing non-ASCII characters.

Unfortunately `fopen()` on Windows does not allow you to use UNICODE in names so you are limited only by ASCII. Which is quite limiting as you can imagine.

You can use `_wfopen` on Windows but it is not standard in the same way as CreateFile.