# How can I get the standard file streams to return a useful error message?

Tags: c++, exception, ifstream

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   try
    {   std::ifstream sFile(argv[1]);
        sFile.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
    } catch (const std::exception &_r)
    {   std::cerr << "exception: " << _r.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In case of the file passed in does not exist, this code prints out with g++ 4.5.2 (yes I know that this is a very old version, but I don't have enough clout to change this):

> "exception: basic_ios::clear"

Using Visual C++ 12:

> "exception: ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error"

Considering that system error messages have already been introduced a very long time ago, I consider this as not acceptable.

Comment: You can never have enough cloud. Have you tried MongoDB? I hear it's web scale.

Comment: (Just in case anyone didn't realize, the above comment is a joke)

Comment: We cannot go back in time and change old compilers to suit your needs. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

#### The C++11 solution

Since C++11, [`std::ios_base::failure` inherits from `std::system_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/failure) so we should be able to `catch` that exception and get the error message right out of it.

```
#include <cstdlib>       // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <fstream>       // std::ifstream
#include <iostream>      // std::cerr, std::endl
#include <system_error>  // std::system_error


int
main()
{
  const auto filename = std::string {"/no/such/file.txt"};
  try
    {
      auto istr = std::ifstream {filename};
      istr.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
      // ...
      istr.close();
    }
  catch (const std::ios_base::failure& e)
    {
      std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
      //std::cerr << "error: " << e.code().message() << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with my GCC 5.3.0 yet. The `catch` never gets activated and the program core-dumps instead. What is even worse is that this means we have to `catch` `std::exception` which will also match all other kinds of exceptions that might not be related to I/O errors. This really bothers me.

#### Using `std::strerror(errno)`

If everything else fails, you can use 'ye good ol' `errno` and obtain a human-readable string via `std::strerror` (which is not thread-safe, by the way). There also is no guarantee that `errno` hasn't been cleared (or re-assigned) between the point where the error occurred and the point you handle the exception. This is because in C++, arbitrary code might have been executed during stack unwinding.

```
#include <cerrno>        // errno
#include <cstdlib>       // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <cstring>       // std::strerror
#include <exception>     // std::exception
#include <fstream>       // std::ifstream
#include <iostream>      // std::cerr, std::endl


int
main()
{
  const auto filename = std::string {"/no/such/file.txt"};
  try
    {
      auto istr = std::ifstream {filename};
      istr.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
      // ...
      istr.close();
    }
  catch (const std::exception&)
    {
      std::cerr << "error: " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Using `std::error_code`s

This solution is only marginally better than using `std::strerror(errno)` but at least it looks more like C++11. The problems are the same except that it is thread-safe.

```
#include <cerrno>        // errno
#include <cstdlib>       // EXIT_SUCCESS, EXIT_FAILURE
#include <exception>     // std::exception
#include <fstream>       // std::ifstream
#include <iostream>      // std::cerr, std::endl
#include <system_error>  // std::error_code, std::system_category


int
main()
{
  const auto filename = std::string {"/no/such/file.txt"};
  try
    {
      auto istr = std::ifstream {filename};
      istr.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
      // ...
      istr.close();
    }
  catch (const std::exception&)
    {
      const auto ec = std::error_code {errno, std::system_category()};
      std::cerr << "error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: -1 for senseless use/show-off of new C++ features -- the use of auto did not make the code more compact. Also the last example using errno suffers from the same problem I mentioned already earlier -- it might be overwritten meanwhile. I also wonder why you would bother to catch a derived class of std::exception -- as the called what() method should return the same. And there is the really senseless call to ifstream::close().

Comment: You should always `catch` specifically the exception you're prepared to handle at the current level. If I `catch` `std::exception`, it will also match all other kinds of errors such as `std::invalid_argument` or `std::bad_alloc` which is probably not what you want here. The explicit call to `close()` is also for a reason. If flushing the buffer and closing the file fails, the destructor won't tell you because it doesn't `throw`; `close` does. Try it out with writing only a few characters to `/dev/full` if you're on a POSIX box.

Answer (score 1):

After a failed system call:

```
std::cout << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
```

Will produce a somewhat useful error message. You will will need to `#include` string.h and errno.h.

C++ exceptions will not be useful here. These POSIX functions will generally produce a more meaningful diagnostic.

Comment: this does not go together with C++ exception handling, as some destructor might have overwritten errno meanwhile.

Comment: Who says that you have to throw an exception?

Comment: @ExcessPhase bit more emphasis on Sam's point: You're generally better off not using stream exceptions. Open the file, check the stream state, if it's not good check `errno` to see why. stream exceptions don't seem to get much love or support.